# need help extracting data from a local .mdf file and send it to my flutter app

Tags: database, flutter, mdf

i am building a test app that will display all the sales made by a shop. this app will be built with the flutter framework, i do not have any problem when it come to front-end, but as of the back-end side of the app i have no idea where to start. i will handle client auth with firebase. i have a test .mdf file filled with test sales numbers and dummy customer data on a separate machine running windows server 2009 r2. My question is whether there is a way to fetch data from that file that is in that server and display it on the app. i have no background in the backend so i will need a thorough explanation on the coding languages and technologies that i will need to use. thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need help figuring out how can i link my sql db server to my flutter app i need to know how can i do it thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up creating an api using nodejs, i made a config file and gave it the db properties as of the username and password i was able to connect to mssqlserver using windows auth and i added a user to give to the config file in the api, i then used ngrok to deploy the running api on the internet and that is what i am using to show the data on the app